# Text decoration <a> within a <div>

Tags: css, hyperlink

I attached a link to a icon font and I can't seem to figure out how to remove the link styling from it.

Here is a part of it
https://jsfiddle.net/bffks6cw/

I've tried

```
  text-decoration: none;
```

but it didn't work. I can't seem to figure it out. 
Any ideas?

Edit:

I did try using .social a { text-decoration: none; }

Here is a pic how it looks.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DG2Kb.jpg

Comment: what result are you expecting?

Comment: The hover effect doesn't work. Need the icon to stay the default color like this https://i.imgur.com/8i6S4eq.jpg without the link attached. I want it to stay the same after I attach the link.

Comment: i edited my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Target `a` instead of the `div`

EDIT: to keep the icon color put `color: inherit`

```
.social a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/bffks6cw/7/

Comment: Tried using that, but nothing changes. Here is how it looks https://i.imgur.com/cj6mUMj.jpg

Answer (score 0):

If you want to style the `anchor`, you need to target the `anchor`.

```
.social a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/bffks6cw/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
.social a {text-decoration: none;}
```

this works.

https://jsfiddle.net/bffks6cw/1/

Answer (score 0):

Add this style,

```
.social a{
   text-decoration: none;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vinodvt22/bffks6cw/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Please Refer this manual for styling links:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp

```
.social a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```